# Can I use JS to test a date and then show HTML code if true?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 lines of HTML code

```
<img class="currentbanner" width="100%" src="src/play1.png">
<img class="currentbanner" width="100%" src="src/play2.png">
<img class="currentbanner" width="100%" src="src/play3.png">
<img class="currentbanner" width="100%" src="src/play4.png">
```

I need to show ONLY a particular png file depending on the date.

If todays date falls between 11/10/2019 (MM/DD/YYYY) and 03/29/2020 show play1.png. If todays date falls between 03/30/2020 and 06/21/2020 show play2.png. etc.

So far I have

```
var dateFrom = "11/10/2019";
var dateTo = "03/29/2020";
var check = Date();

var from = Date.parse(dateFrom);
var to   = Date.parse(dateTo);
var check = Date.parse(dateCheck );

if((check <= to && check >= from)) {     
    ?HTML CODE HERE?    
}
else {
    ?LOOP AGAIN 3 TIMES?
}
```

EDIT: I also need those lines of HTML to fall between div tags so they can pick up some CSS code.

Comment: I think you want `var check = new Date();` which will set it to the current date.

Comment: @sumnerEvans Thanks. I added that.

Answer (score 0):

Just basic date comparisons. I would have one image and just set the source.

```js
var currentDate = new Date()
var img = document.querySelector(".bannerImage")
if (currentDate < new Date("12/01/2019")) {
  img.src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300"
} else if (currentDate < new Date("2/01/2020")) {
  img.src = "http://placekitten.com/300/300"
} else if (currentDate < new Date("4/01/2020")) {
  img.src = "http://placekitten.com/400/300"
} else {
  img.src = "http://placekitten.com/500/300"
}
```

```html
<img class="bannerImage" />
```

Comment: When I try this is just adds a line break. As if the page doesn't place the image correctly... Does this pick up my CSS correctly?

Comment: sounds like you have a JavaScript error on the page. Probably put the script in the head and it ran before the element was added to the page

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to have 1 image tag:

```
<img id="bannerImg" class="currentbanner" width="100%" src="src/placeHolder.png">
```

Then set the image accordingly:

```
var currentDate = new Date()
var img = document.getElementById("bannerImg")

if (currentDate < new Date("12/01/2019")) {
  img.src = "src/play1.png"
} else if (currentDate < new Date("2/01/2020")) {
  img.src = "src/play2.png"
} else if (currentDate < new Date("4/01/2020")) {
  img.src = "src/play3.png"
} else {
  img.src = "src/play4.png"
}
```

Comment: For this to work, does it have to be on a server? It just shows the placeholder each time regardless of the dates I enter....

Comment: Not should run on the client fine.  I noticed I had typos in the image paths, I fixed them